# Why aren't existential quantification and datakinds working together?

Tags: haskell, ghc, dependent-type, existential-type, data-kinds

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, ExistentialQuantification, KindSignatures #-}
import Data.Proxy

data Type t= forall (a :: t). Type (Proxy a)
```

gives the error

```
Type variable ‘t’ used in a kind
In the kind ‘t’
In the definition of data constructor ‘Type’
In the data declaration for ‘Type’
```

But `t` is a Kind variable, not a type variable. What's going on?

Comment: You can't yet mix types and kinds in the concrete syntax. The best you can do is `data Type (tp :: KProxy t) = forall (a :: t) . Type (Proxy a)` (although I don't see how useful this data type would be, but that's a different issue altogether.

Answer (score 9):

Prior to GHC 8, there are no kind bindings allowed, anywhere. Here, we have to use kind proxies. In this case we can do:

```
import Data.Proxy

data Type (kp :: KProxy k) = forall (a :: k). Type (Proxy a)
```

With GHC 8, you can indeed write your original version:

```
{-# language TypeInType #-}

data Type t = forall (a :: t). Type (Proxy a)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if that exact definition works in GHC 8 though, since Type is builtin in that version.

Comment: I just tried it and it works in ghci. We only get `Type` if we import `Data.Kind`.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments of type constructors are types, not kinds. So `data Type t = ...` means `t` is a type variable.

In GHC 8.0 the TypeInType extension removes the distinction between types and kinds, allowing your program to be accepted if you enable it (and GHC will suggest enabling the extension if you don't).